# Django Class Based Views: How to use username instead of ID to get data from extended model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models: `User` and `UserProfile` the first one contains fields like `username`, `first_name`, etc. And the second one contains all extra fields that Django admin does not provide but I need it, like: `reputation`. My question is, how to get all data from both models?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from userprofiles.views import UserDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^profile/username/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', UserDetailView.as_view()),
)
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
# from .models import UserProfile (This contains custom fields)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'

    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'profile.html'
```

**profile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>

<section>
    {{user.username}}<br>
    {{userprofile.reputation}}<br>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point I'm getting only username without reputation in my profile.html when I access to: `http://localhost:8000/profile/username/MY_USERNAME/`

Comment: To avoid having that kind of issues you could extend the default user and add it your fields directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `User` object is present in the context. Use the reverse relationship to access the profile from the `User` model:

```
{{ user.userprofile.reputation }}
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)